# Add method of calendar gives wrong value?

Tags: java, android, date, calendar

I am trying to change the date on a button click using `c.add(Calendar.DATE,1)`. It should increment the day by 1. The problem is that when the month changes, the date increments to 32 instead of the expected 1 (In January). The month changes to Feb but the date changes to 32 and so on, e.g. `32-Feb-2016`.

```
 final TextView tv_date = (TextView) dialyReportView.findViewById(R.id.datepicker);
 @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Calendar c;
                c= Calendar.getInstance();
                c.add(Calendar.DATE,1);
                SimpleDateFormat df= new SimpleDateFormat("DD-MMM-yyyy");
                String nextDate = df.format(c.getTime());
                tv_date.setText(nextDate);
            }
        });
```

I am new to programming so any help is appreciated. Thank you! :)

Comment: Thanks @AndyTurner can you help with the solution :)

Comment: Please read about writing a [Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](http://www.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Is the fact that this is Android code relevant, or can you reproduce the same problem in a simple Java program which could be run simply by somebody reading this question?

Comment: Your edit doesn't leave complete code. For example, what is `c`, and this code can't be run by itself.

Comment: @AndyTurner yes this may be reproduced in java.I have edited the question please check is it clear now?

Comment: This code doesn't reproduce the problem that you describe, unless you happen to be running it on the 31st of January. And it still can't be run standalone - there is nothing to "click", and how do I see the updated value in `tv_date`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that you are using `D` (day of year) instead of `d` (day of month). For example, the following code outputs `31-Jan-2015` and `32-Feb-2015`:

```
 Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
 c.set(2015, 0, 31);
 c.SimpleDateFormat df= new SimpleDateFormat("DD-MMM-yyyy");
 System.out.println(df.format(c.getTime()));
 c.add(Calendar.DATE,1);
 System.out.println(df.format(c.getTime()));
```

whereas the following outputs `31-Jan-2015` and `01-Feb-2015`:

```
 Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
 c.set(2015, 0, 31);
 c.SimpleDateFormat df= new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy");
 System.out.println(df.format(c.getTime()));
 c.add(Calendar.DATE,1);
 System.out.println(df.format(c.getTime()));
```

Answer (score 3):

Change your date format code line as below.

SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy");

Answer (score 2):

Check https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

`DD` is for day in year and `dd` is for day in month

```
Letter  Date or Time Component  Presentation    Examples
D       Day in year             Number          189
d       Day in month            Number          10
```